# Getting contents of all Jupyter Notebook code cells in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook

I am writing a JavaScript code which will gather the contents of ALL code cells of a Jupyter notebook and send it on an external server.

I am trying something among the lines of...

```
function sendNewData() {
    let cells = Jupyter.notebook.get_cells();
    let actualCells = [];

    cells.forEach(function (cell) {
        if(cell.cell_type == "code" && cell.metadata.created) {
            let creationTime = new Date(cell.metadata.created);
            let timeDiff = seminarStartedDate - creationTime;

            if (timeDiff > 0) {
                actualCells.push(cell.get_text());
            }
        }
    })

    let url = "https://localhost:7199/Seminar/students/" + seminarId + "/" + studentId;

    const response = fetch(url, {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(actualCells),
    })

    console.log("sent data");
}
```

For some reason, this code won't even work because of "ReferenceError: Jupyter is not defined at sendNewData." (basically the second string of my solution) Why? The internet is filled with suggestions using Jupyter.notebook methods. Have they been discontinued? What to do?

Comment: Did you load `Jupyter` library?

Comment: No? Keep in mind that I (at least right now) use Jupyter Notebook (not Lab) from browser.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Jupyter.notebook (or Jupyter.anything, really) was cut from Notebook >=7.